# Particles: How to stop object from sinking into mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects, particles, fluid-simulation, rigidbody

As you can see in the picture, no matter what object or plane, they sink halfway almoststicking to the bottom of the plane. I haven't found any solutions on this yet and figured it would be of great help to myself and a lot of people to have a solution here on stackexchange.

All help appreciated :)

[image: from my blender file]

Comment: Deflect Size option in the particlesystem settings?

Comment: I've tried ticking and unticking it, left unticked the objects are sunk even deeper to the mesh. Ticked the appear as on the photo. Gonna experiment with some weight paint, maybe that will do?

Comment: Opened up a new blender project, tried to keep it as basic and simple as possible, two planes and a basic uv sphere. Still they sink slightly into the mesh. Deflect size and solidify does nothing. If I use the basic halo particle it seems to work though.

Comment: I'm gonna further other aspects of my project as I've been stuck on this for hours now. Any help is appreciated still though. 
What I want is for object x to rain down on plane y, and stacking untill it overflows. I'm sure it's possible as is, but would love for the first few objects not to sink into the mesh itself.
Thank you.

Comment: Okay, sooo ... I think the problem lay in my object itself, because it works with two basic planes and UV sphere. Maybe I just made my object a little to muddy for the collision to read. Will update.